NX Generating dist Directory Inside Project Folder Instead of Root Directory
I'm using Nx for my monorepo setup, and I've run into an issue where the build artifacts are generated inside the project folder under dist, rather than at the root level as I intended.

Error:
 NX   Running target serve for project graphql-api and 1 task it depends on:

————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————— 

> nx run graphql-api:build:production


> nx run graphql-api:serve:development

 NX   Nx Daemon is not enabled. Assets will not be updated when they are changed.
[ watch ] build succeeded, watching for changes...
C:\Users\asfat\projects\web\man-cog-full-poc\manulife\node_modules\@nx\js\src\executors\node\node.impl.js:313
    throw new Error(`Could not find ${fileToRun}. Make sure your build succeeded.`);
          ^
Error: Could not find C:\Users\asfat\projects\web\man-cog-full-poc\manulife\dist\packages\graphql-api\main.js. Make sure your build succeeded.
    at fileToRunCorrectPath (C:\Users\asfat\projects\web\man-cog-full-poc\manulife\node_modules\@nx\js\src\executors\node\node.impl.js:313:11)
    at C:\Users\asfat\projects\web\man-cog-full-poc\manulife\node_modules\@nx\js\src\executors\node\node.impl.js:99:49
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.start (C:\Users\asfat\projects\web\man-cog-full-poc\manulife\node_modules\@nx\js\src\executors\node\node.impl.js:93:36)
    at async Timeout.processQueue [as _onTimeout] (C:\Users\asfat\projects\web\man-cog-full-poc\manulife\node_modules\@nx\js\src\executors\node\node.impl.js:64:13)
Node.js v20.12.2

Problem: When I build my project using Nx, the dist directory is created inside the project folder (e.g., packages/graphql-api/dist). I need the dist directory to be generated at the root level of the workspace (e.g., dist/graphql-api).
Configuration:
Here’s how my project.json file is configured:
{
  "projects": {
    "graphql-api": {
      "root": "packages/graphql-api",
      "sourceRoot": "packages/graphql-api/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:build",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/graphql-api",  // Desired output path
            "main": "packages/graphql-api/src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "packages/graphql-api/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": []
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@nrwl/node:execute",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "graphql-api:build"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Issue: Despite setting the outputPath to dist/packages/graphql-api, Nx still generates the dist directory inside the project folder. The build artifacts are placed at packages/graphql-api/dist instead of dist/packages/graphql-api.
What I’ve Tried:

Rebuilt the project using nx build graphql-api.
Verified the outputPath configuration.

Questions:

How can I configure Nx to generate the dist directory at the root level of the workspace?
Is there a specific setting or configuration I might be missing to ensure that the build artifacts are placed at the root level?

Additional Information:
Nx version: 19.7.3
Node.js version: 20.12.2
Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!
